# Не выбираются поля со связанной таблицы Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

У меня есть такой запрос

```
return Logs::find()
            ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id = logs.user_id')
            ->orderBy('logs.id desc')
            ->offset($limit)
            ->limit(20)
            ->all();
```

Он возвращает все поля таблицы `logs`. Но мне нужно еще вернуть логин с таблицы `user`. Пробовал добавил так

```
->select(['logs.*', 'user.username'])
```

не сработало. Где у меня ошибка?

Полный текст запроса с select

```
return Logs::find()
            ->select(['logs.*', 'user.username'])
            ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id = logs.user_id')
            ->orderBy('logs.id desc')
            ->offset($limit)
            ->limit(20)
            ->all();
```

Comment: приведите полный текст запроса, где вы юзаете `select`

Comment: `$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['logs.id', 'user.username'])
    ->from('user')
    ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id = logs.user_id')
    ->orderBy('logs.id desc')
    ->offset($limit)
    ->limit(20)`

Comment: добавил полный текст

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц мне нужно через модель ActiveRecord. или через модель этого не можно сделать?

Comment: можно конешно ))

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете в модели `Logs` создать связь с таблицей `user`:

```php
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, ['id' => 'user_id'])->select(['username']);
}
```

И вызвать эту связь через метод `joinWith()`:

```php
return Logs::find()
    ->joinWith('user')
    ->orderBy('logs.id DESC')
    ->all();
```

Ваш же пример сформирует правильный SQL-запрос, но, по какой-то причине, `select()` в Active Record для связанных таблиц не сработает.

Comment: у меня есть описанная вами связь

Comment: @Diefair, в чём тогда проблема? Вызовите её и у вас будет поле `user.username` в объекте `_related`.

Comment: и описанный вами способ через `joinWith` тоже не сработал

Comment: @Diefair, что у вас выводится в результате, какие-то ошибки есть?

Comment: нет, просто выводятся поля только из таблицы Logs, а мне надо и юзера получить

Comment: я забыл указать, что я обращаюсь на сервер с фронта и получаю ответ в json. может это как то влияет. потому что в _related действительно выбирает данные

Comment: Причин может быть много, как вариант посмотрите метод `fields()` в модели `Logs`.